# Combine results of 2 queries into 1 result then pass to DGV

Tags: c#, linq

I need to combine before and after below into one result then pass it to a datagridview.  I used before + after as I have no idea how to combine results.

```
        private void textBox6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses3DataContext db = new DataClasses3DataContext();

        int matchedAdd = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                          where c.HOUSE_NO.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c.Direction.Contains(textBox2.Text) && c.street.Contains(textBox3.Text) && c.SUFF.Contains(textBox4.Text)
                          select c.ID).SingleOrDefault();

        var before = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                      where c.ID < matchedAdd
                      orderby c.PARCEL descending
                      select c).Take(6);

        var after = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                     where c.ID > matchedAdd
                     orderby c.PARCEL
                     select c).Take(6);

        var endResult = before + after;

        dgvBRT.DataSource = endResult;
        dgvBRT.Databind();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` you want there is either `before.Concat(after)` or `before.Union(after)`, depending on how you want duplicates to be handled (union removes duplicates; concatenation does not; for example `{1,2,2,3}` concat `{3,4}` is `{1,2,2,3,3,4}`, where-as `{1,2,2,3}` union `{3,4}` is `{1,2,3,4}` (although it is questionable whether the order is defined in the union case)

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I used Concat as there shouldn't ever be a duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

You can usion the union-operator:

```
var endresult = before.Union(after);
```